# Google maps API v3 - is it possible to add a non specific location, such as a continent or a country?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have recently developed an application that uses Google maps APi v3, in order to allow my customers to specify their location, and to indicated this location on the map upon the request of their users(end users).

Now, I have 2 issues:

I'm using the API in 2 languages, and sometimes they are getting messed up, and get pretty much ugly.

Now, optimally, I would like to allow the user to change the language of the map in real time, allowing to add locations in both of the languages, depending on the needs of the end users(the users of my users), but from a research the I have conducted, it appears to be impossible, unless you make a second call for the API in the same page, and I am not into violating Google's terms of use.

What I've come up with, is that I need to get each location Geo-coded, and then translated to the other language, then I'll be able to use the appropriate location name for each user and page.

The second issue, is that Google doesn't seem to recognize a non specific type of location, on global level.
Let's say that I type 'United states of America' or 'Europe', now, some users would liker to display just that, instead the Google API seems to complete the address to something like: 'Texas, united states', or 'Stockholm, Sweden, Europe'.
That's the location that it places the marker on, and I suppose that this is what Geocoding does, fetching a specific location, but is there a good, bug - proof way around it, instead of analyzing the input text of the user perhaps, or somehow filtering and manipulating the result from the API, which is clearly a violation of the terms of use?.

Thanks in advance guys!, I've been smashing my head into the wall over this for the past couple of weeks.

Comment: I guess Google doesn't offer the possibility to specify "Europe" as a location because it would make little sense - what physical  location would  you want it to translate to?

Comment: If you are about to geocode location such as Europe or United states of America - it will work, I just tested that. It will place marker however to pre-defined place which google has chosen, but it will definitely land respectively to europe or united states spot, more detailed the location - more detailed the marker spot - makes sense?

Comment: Yes, but Google might randomly add a parameter to the country_short, country_long, or locality fields in the JSON response.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: since its JSON response why dont you just pick the data from it what you want to use and skip the rest? adding code example about geocoding what i mean.

Comment: My application has auto complete in it, with an input field.
Filtering the response can be an option, although it is the last resort, and even then, how can I determine which information is useful and which isn't without a tricky algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Geocoder API of Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

You define the geocoder like that:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

Take a look at this example: http://geocodezip.com/v3_zoom2countrySelectList.html for the following

Comment: Thanks! 

Although my application has an free input text field, with an auto complete feature in it, integrated with the Google API.

So basically, I need a solution that will allow my users to input both specific(street,city, country) and non-specific(country, continent, region) locations.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
O.

Comment: Geocoder accepts address, zipcode, street name, country etc in input. Its exactly the search input of google maps. When you go at maps.google.com you can type any location you want in the search field...

Comment: I thought perhaps I should use the boundaries in order to define a location, and then display it using those boundaries.

What do you guys think?.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example where I geocode and swap between two contries, plus print geocode debug stuff using

`console.log(results[0]);`

and also,

`alert('Got formatted to: ' + results[0].formatted_address);`

"Europe" and "United states" should be present. Marker are placed to latLng values which geocoding returns.

It uses gmap3 library to launch a map since its an example I recently build, but all the relevant stuff is normal google maps geocoding code. Use it as you like.

Check out **[JS fiddle (geocode using country name)](http://jsfiddle.net/MDFTN/6/)**

In order to geocode based on visible viewport you need to get and pass current bounds for geocoder, I created an example which geocodes viewport bounds and centers map to position based on actual geocoder result.

Check out **[JS fiddle (geocode using viewport bounds)](http://jsfiddle.net/NUkCs/)**

Comment: I thought perhaps I should use the boundaries in order to define a location, and then display it using those boundaries. What do you guys think?.

Comment: you mean viewport boundaries?

Comment: ^ I updated my answer to demonstrate that, as you can see it geocodes closest address based on visible viewport - it can move slightly away from the inital positions since every spot in the world doesn't really have readable addresses ;)